# Turn string with () as function brackets into expression

Tags: import, string-manipulation, formatting, expression-manipulation

I have a text file with an equation where all the brackets are formatted as (). For example I read in the equation 2*(Re(a)+Im(b)) as a string. Now I am wondering if I can make this into an expression where mathematica correctly recognizes Re(a) and Im(b) as functions. In some sense I just have to change 2*(Re(a)+Im(b)) into 2*(Re[a]+Im[b]) but I am not sure if this is possible to do automatically.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load the file on to an online service like Google Drive etc. and create a public and accessible link to it that can be included with your post.  This will facilitate the provision of concrete answers as opposed to speculative or generic ones. Thanks.

Comment: I think it will be easier if you fix the generating program to generate valid Mathematica code.

Comment: Does it fit your needs? `ToExpression["2*(Re(a)+Im(b))", TraditionalForm, HoldComplete]`

Comment: @Kuba it indeed fits nicely, thank you very much for the quick response!